# Null in String.Format args throws NullReferenceException even arg isn't in resultative string

Tags: c#, .net, exception, string-formatting, nullreferenceexception

I have a `null` in one of arguments in `String.Format()` so call throws `NullReferenceException`. Why does check take place even the argument isn't in resultant string?

```
class Foo
{
    public Exception Ex { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f1 = new Foo() { Ex = new Exception("Whatever") };
        var f2 = new Foo();         

        var error1 = String.Format((f1.Ex == null) ? "Eror" : "Error: {0}", f1.Ex.Message); // works
        var error2 = String.Format((f2.Ex == null) ? "Eror" : "Error: {0}", f2.Ex.Message); // NullReferenceException 
    }
}
```

Are there any workarounds except two calls separated by `if()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're going to end up evaluating `f2.Ex.Message` in either case.

Should be:

```
var error2 = (f2.Ex == null) ? "Eror" : String.Format("Error: {0}", f2.Ex.Message);
```

Comment: +1 for the code example, which explains the point better than Darins answer.

Answer (score 6):

It is not `string.Format` that is throwing the exception but this: `f2.Ex.Message`. You are calling the `Message` getter on `Ex` property which is null.